# Custom PS1 prompt sometimes causes lines to be overwritten

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm having a problem with my `PS1` setting, which I've set up to show the git repository branch and status.

Sometimes I have problem with overwritten lines in the terminal. I don't know why. If I set `PS1="$ "` it works fine. Actually, the setting below works well on my another macbook pro with macOS Catalina/Terminal.app/bash.

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

function init {
    case $OSTYPE in
        linux*)
            MAGENTA='\e[0;31m'
            GREEN='\e[0;32m'
            ORANGE='\e[1;33m'
            BLUE='\e[0;34m'
            PURPLE='\e[0;35m'
            WHITE='\e[0;37m'
            RESET='\e[0m'
            ;;
        darwin*)
            MAGENTA="\033[1;31m"
            GREEN="\033[1;32m"
            ORANGE="\033[1;33m"
            BLUE="\033[1;34m"
            PURPLE="\033[1;35m"
            WHITE="\033[1;37m"
            RESET="\033[m"
            ;;
    esac
}
init

function git_color {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

  if [[ ! $git_status =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
    echo -e $MAGENTA
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "Your branch is ahead of" ]]; then
    echo -e $ORANGE
  elif [[ $git_status =~ "nothing to commit" ]]; then
    echo -e $GREEN
  else
    echo -e $PURPLE
  fi
}

function git_branch {
  local git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
  local on_branch="On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
  local on_branch_zh="位于分支 ([^${IFS}]*)"
  local on_commit="HEAD detached at ([^${IFS}]*)"

  if [[ $git_status =~ $on_branch ]]; then
    local branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($branch)"
  elif [[ $git_status =~ $on_branch_zh ]]; then
    local branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($branch)"
  elif [[ $git_status =~ $on_commit ]]; then
    local commit=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "($commit)"
  fi
}

#export PS1="\[${PURPLE}\]\u\[$GREEN\]@\[$ORANGE\]\h \[$BLUE\]\w \$(git_color)\$(git_branch)\[$RESET\] \[$GREEN\]\$\[$RESET\] "
export PS1="\[$PURPLE\]\u\[$GREEN\]@\[$ORANGE\]kn \[$BLUE\]\W \[\$(git_color)\]\[\$(git_branch)\] \[$GREEN\]\$\[$RESET\] "
export PS2="\[$ORANGE\]→ \[$RESET\]"
```

Answer (score 6):

`\[` and `\]` should only surround non-printing characters so that bash knows which sequences move the cursor and which do not. Using them improperly can cause bash to lose track of the cursor position and refresh the terminal incorrectly.

You have it around all of the color codes—rightly so—but should not have it around `\$(git_branch)` since that prints visible text.

```
\[\$(git_branch)\]
^^              ^^
```